# Piece-Wise Discontinuity & Continuity

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

When is the following function continuous?  How would i go about listing the removable 
discontinuities and then redeﬁne the function so that it is now continuous 
in those places?

$$f(x)= \begin {cases} \sqrt{2x}+7&\text{if }x <2\\
0\
&\text{if }x = 2\\
3^x&\text{if }x > 2 \end {cases}$$

Comment: That's five questions in an hour. Slow down, have a look at the answers, digest them; then, if you still have questions, come back with one or two more.

Comment: Sorry im just trying to learn as much as i can and figure this all out my notes are allover but ill try to limit it thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is discontinuous at $x = 2$. Approaching from the left, the limit is $\sqrt{(2)(2)} + 7 = 9$. Approaching from the right, you have $3^2 = 9$. However at $x = 2$, the function is defined to be $0 \neq 9$. Hence it is discontinuous at $x = 2$, but can be made continuous by defining $f(2) = 9$.

Comment: So we need f(2)= 9 in order for it to be continuous?

Comment: @soniccool Yes.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try drawing a picture of $f(x)$, even if it's just from, say, $x=1$ to $x=3.$ Try to figure out the limit of $f(x)$ to the left and right of $x=2$. Is it the same? What happens when $x=2$?

**Remark:** If the limit on the left and right hand side is the same (i.e. the function approaches the same $y$-value from both sides of the neighboring $x$ value) , there is a good chance that the function is continuous. Often one defines continuity as "not having to lift your pencil up when you graph the function." However, note that there is indeed a point discontinuity at $x = 2$ due to the limit from the LHS being $9$ and the limit on the RHS being $9$, but the function is **defined** to be $0$ at $x=2$. This implies a point discontinuity which can be removed if you **re-define** $f(2)$ to equal $9$ for your original function. This would make $f(x)$ continuous **everywhere** along the real numbers.